# Google Calendar link is not working after Publish Event?

Tags: google-calendar

I want to create something like this **Add to Calendar**: [Google Calendar™](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=GoToWebinar%20-%20The%20pain%20points%20of%20personalization%20and%20how%20to%20fix%20them&dates=20170726T160000/20170726T170000&ctz=Europe/London&details=1.%20Click%20and%20join%20at%20the%20specified%20time%20and%20date:%0Ahttps://global.gotowebinar.com/join/3342042942423795715/860198447%20(https://global.gotowebinar.com/join/3342042942423795715/860198447)%0ANote:%20This%20link%20should%20not%20be%20shared%20with%20others%20it%20is%20unique%20to%20you.%0A%0A2.%20More%20webinar%20details:%0Ahttps://attendee.gotowebinar.com/additionalInfo.tmpl?duplicate%3Dfalse%26webinar%3D3342042942423795715%26aregistrantConfirmation%3D120923573550721805%20(https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/additionalInfo.tmpl?duplicate%3Dfalse%26webinar%3D3342042942423795715%26aregistrantConfirmation%3D120923573550721805)&location=GoToWebinar&pli=1&uid=1501150956@addevent.com&sf=true&output=xml#eventpage_6)

To achieve the results have created a Google Calendar event invitation, please see the screenshot below.

**Screenshot 1**

[image: Example 1]

After saving event, I have generated a link by **Publish event** and got the link which is below.

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&tmeid=NGh1NzdzODhiZ3JuY21tbmg4MTVpbmZ0bzggcmh1bC5rYXNoeWFwQG0&tmsrc=rhul.kashyap%40gmail.com

When I am sending this link to others this is opening the page to create new untitled event as per shown in below screenshot.

**Screenshot 2**

[image]

Please help me to achieve the desired results.
**Add to Calendar**: [Google Calendar™](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=GoToWebinar%20-%20The%20pain%20points%20of%20personalization%20and%20how%20to%20fix%20them&dates=20170726T160000/20170726T170000&ctz=Europe/London&details=1.%20Click%20and%20join%20at%20the%20specified%20time%20and%20date:%0Ahttps://global.gotowebinar.com/join/3342042942423795715/860198447%20(https://global.gotowebinar.com/join/3342042942423795715/860198447)%0ANote:%20This%20link%20should%20not%20be%20shared%20with%20others%20it%20is%20unique%20to%20you.%0A%0A2.%20More%20webinar%20details:%0Ahttps://attendee.gotowebinar.com/additionalInfo.tmpl?duplicate%3Dfalse%26webinar%3D3342042942423795715%26aregistrantConfirmation%3D120923573550721805%20(https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/additionalInfo.tmpl?duplicate%3Dfalse%26webinar%3D3342042942423795715%26aregistrantConfirmation%3D120923573550721805)&location=GoToWebinar&pli=1&uid=1501150956@addevent.com&sf=true&output=xml#eventpage_6)

Comment: did you find a solution? I have exactly the same issue ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the soloution:

**The calendar that contains the event needs to be published.**

As I did not want to make my calendar public I just created a new one.

---

*UPDATE: As the Google Calendar interface changed recently and my original screenshots were in German, I've uploaded new ones.*

---

## Step 1:

[image]

## Step 2:

[image]

## Step 3:

[image]

## Step 4:

[image]

Comment: It would be nicer that the screenshots shows the text in English

Comment: @Rubén You are right - I've uploaded new screenshots :)